# MATLAB export Live Script as pdf with line numbers displayed?

Tags: matlab, export, export-to-pdf, line-numbers

I have a MATLAB Live Script (.mlx) that I am exporting to a pdf in order to print/share. I have the line numbers displayed in the script while working with it in the live editor, but when I export the script to a pdf, the line numbers are gone.

Is there a way to make the line numbers display in the pdf output as well?
To be clear, I have already enabled line numbers using the 'View' tab in MATLAB. It is the pdf output that I am trying to get the line numbers to display in.

Thank you!